# Firewall bypass techniques in source code

Tags: c++, networking, p2p, firewall

I am planning to write a software, kind of p2p that needs to bypass the firewall. I know there are many ways of bypassing firewalls using many third party tools, as from my google searches. However I could not get much results on how to write a p2p software that can go beyond firewall to connect to the nodes.

So my question is to know algorithms or techniques that I can use in my source code to bypass firewalls - both the NAT firewalls and the software/personal firewalls as well.

Kindly help me understand how to do this with your suggestions or past experiences.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "bypass"? Do you mean "tunneling"?

Comment: Hi Nim, I want to have a P2P system that will be widespread and can be behind firewalls. I want the communication to happen seamlessly even though some peer systems are behind firewall - FIREWALL BYPASS. I know what tunneling is but do not know if I could apply it in this context. Can you please make me understand? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use [uPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp) and [Internet Gateway Device Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) if it is available to forward ports in the firewall. If it is not available, use [TCP hole punching techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching).

Comment: Hi Maxim, the ones you sent seems interesting, I will read through them and see if I can implement them. Can I ask you this - If I have NO IDEA wat type or kind the firewall is going to be, which of the 3 three would you suggest? Wat would you do?

Comment: You need to implement all three. This is what Skype does.

Comment: Okay then, I will get it started. Thank you Maxim! Do you reckon these three would be enough to break any wall of fire OUT there?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, one technique that tends to work well is running everything over plain old HTTP on port 80. This works because most firewalls will let through HTTP traffic to allow web browsing.

The catches are that it's not a terribly efficient approach compared to something specialised for p2p, and it's not guaranteed to work because there are some firewalls that are smart enough to detect when HTTP is being abused in this way. Some also will restrict access to port 80 specifically to prevent this kind of thing.

Comment: Mac, thanks for the idea. That's a cool idea but I came across this before. I do not want to follow this particular approach. Have you come across an idea that *reportedly* is being used by some popular P2P apps called Nat-2-NAT or punching a wall in the firewall??

Comment: @Danny: sorry, I know very little about any of this. My answer was based purely on some stuff I stumbled across a while back, not any real interest/involvement in such things.

Comment: No probs Mac, I do appreciate your effort to share your knowledge - Thanks! I will keep looking for the best approach...

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls tend to allow outgoing traffic but block incoming traffic unless there is a pre-existing session. For TCP this is easy, once the connection is established, the firewall will allow connection in both directions.

For UDP this is a bit more tricky since there is no concept of a session. Protocols like UDP based DNS are request response protocols so once a request is sent by the client, a response is expected from the server. The firewall will register the request on a given port and allow a response to come back in a short time later.

So one trick is that if one is expecting UDP traffic is to sent a small amount of garbage data. This will be ignored by the server but hopefully will open the firewall to allow incoming traffic.

Comment: Thanks Doron, I will certainly have this as one of my solutions.